# Use nuxt.js dynamic routing to pass parameters

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am going to query the database to return the result after receiving a parameter in the dynamic route, and find that the console reports an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

When I went to see the request, I found that the first request returned the data, and then sent the same request but the spliced parameter was `null` and reported the error.

[image]

This is the second request 304

[image]

This is my page code.
`

```
 <templat>
  <div class="wrapper qa-content">
    <div class="qa-title">
      <div class="fl title">
        <h2>{{problem.title}}</h2>
        <p>
          <span
          >{{labes(index)}}</span>
          <span>{{timeago(problem.createtime)}}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
import "~/assets/css/page-sj-qa-detail.css";
import axios from "axios";
import problemApi from "@/api/problem";
import replyApi from "@/api/reply";
import labelApi from "@/api/label";
export default {
  asyncData({ params }) {
    return axios
      .all([
        problemApi.findById(params.id),
        replyApi.findByProId(params.id),
        problemApi.findPL(params.id)
      ])
      .then(
        axios.spread(function(pojo, replyList, labelList) {
          return {
            problemId: params.id,
            replyList: replyList.data.data,
            problem: pojo.data.data,
            labelList: labelList.data.data
          };
        })
      );
  },
  data() {
    return {
      CurrentreplyId: "",
      commentList: [],
      labelName: [],
      textarea: "",
      dialogVisible: false,
      content: "",
      editorOption: {
        // some quill options
        modules: {
          toolbar: [
            [{ size: ["small", false, "large"] }],
            ["bold", "italic"],
            [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
            ["link", "image"],
            ["blockquote", "code-block"]
          ]
        }
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("app init, my quill insrance object is:", this.myQuillEditor);
  },
  methods: {

    labes(index) {
      console.log(this.labelList);
       labelApi.findOne(this.labelList[index].labelid).then(res => {
        this.labelName.push(res.data.data.labelname);
        console.log(this.labelName);
      });
    },
     check(id) {
      console.log(id);
       replyApi.findByParentid(id).then(res => {
        this.commentList = res.data.data;
      });
    },
    shows(item) {
      console.log(item.id);
      if (item.content === null || item.content === "" || item.content === "") {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

`

This page is dynamically routed from the previous page.

`<nuxt-link :to="'/qa/items/'+item.id" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</nuxt-link>`

Comment: Could you share some of your code as well? That would make it easier for us to help you. So the problem is not your request, but rather that the query parameter (I assume you have a product id or something similar (first time it is `2`) is not present. Anyway you make a request...
So you'd have to find out what is happening in your code, why does it get null and makes such a request...?
But as I said, share some code where you make those requests and maybe I can see more.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this rookie. I have posted some of the code. If you write well, please forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think that helps. If I understand you correctly you do the following:

1. You are on a previous page
2. You click on the nuxt-link with the item id in the route
3. Your new route loads and you get an error: Because your page fetches the data from the API twice (but you did not reload the page) is that correct?

If so, I am not sure why your `asyncData` is executed twice, but you could probably solve it like this:

```
asyncData({ params }) {
if (params.id) {
    return axios
  .all([...
}
```

This would make sure that your request is only made ifan ID is present and it would not send null.

Honestly I don't know why the request is resent...

I also don't really understand how your API looks like. I see that it somehow returns promises, and that you can call methods on it... Something I haven't seen in such a context, but OK :).

Besides that you seem to execute further API calls in your methods.
Maybe that is the problem:
`<span>{{labes(index)}}</span>`
I don't see what would be passed into this method. This index is not defined...
When then calling the

`labes()` (did you mean `labels`?) method, you execute
`labelApi.findOne(this.labelList[index].labelid)`
but as index is undefined, I think `this.labelList[index]` will not return something useful and you make a request there?

(Depending on what your `api.findOne()` method does. Could it be that itself sends a request to an actual remote API?)

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found the problem based on your answer. I found that the second request is because the page that imported the header has an img that is not loaded, so each request may refresh the page, but there are no parameters. Passed in so there is a problem with null.

Comment: Alright.  Your example did not show anything about a header... ‍♂️